# Global variable value in Worksheet_Calculate() event handler is always incorrect

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with a global variable whose value is not always correct.

I have declared it like this:

```
Public NumRows As Long
```

It is used to hold the number of used rows on Sheet 1. The variable is public because multiple macros use it.

It is initialised here:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  NumRows = Worksheets("TableSize").Range("A1").Value
  MsgBox "NumRows = " & NumRows
End Sub
```

`MsgBox` was inserted simply to verify that the code was working. Sheet `TableSize` only has information in `A1`. At this point, `NumRows = 32` which is correct.

This is the event handler in Sheet `TableSize` that is causing problems:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()    

    Dim n As Long
    n = Worksheets("TableSize").Range("A1").Value 'A1 contains the formula "=ROW(INDEX(Sheet1,1,1))+ROWS(Sheet1)-1" used to count rows on Sheet 1
    MsgBox n & "NumRows=" & NumRows
    If n = NumRows Then Exit Sub
    If n > NumRows Then Call NewDatabaseEntry

    NumRows = n    

End Sub
```

`MsgBox` returns `32` for `n` like it should, but `0` for `NumRows`, even though `NumRows` was correctly set in the `Workbook_Open()` handler!

The desire is for `n` to always equal `NumRows` unless I actually add a row, so that only then will `NewDataEntry` (correctly) create a new data entry on another sheet.

Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: Do you use Option Explicit in your modules? If not, please add it and report the errors you get.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you started with a description of the problem, what you're trying to achieve, and mentioned Excel+VBA. I'd recommend some editing, which would help others understand how to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the solution is very simple. It involves two parts.

The first part solves your immediate issue. All you need to do is move the `NumRows` global variable declaration from the "ThisWorkbook" module (where it seems like you have it now) to a standard module. (The "Module1" module you mentioned in a previous question is fine.)

Your `Workbook_Open()` event handler will still be able to access the variable, as will code in every other module, and everything should still work (or not if there are other issues) just as it currently does.

The second part addresses the more general problem of why what you did didn't cause an error. It will also help avoid a lot of other issues in the future. Just as Storax has suggested, although I will word it a bit stronger, you *must* use the `Option Explicit` statement at the top of every code module.

The best way to do this is set up the VBIDE to do so automatically. Go to `Tools > Options… > Editor` and check the `Require Variable Declaration` option. (Make sure you click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button ;-) )

From now on, `Option Explicit` will automatically be added to all new modules that you create, and to all the modules in new workbooks that you create. However, *existing* modules will need to be manually updated.

---

Another good idea, according to the DRY principle, would be to place the table size code in a function. Together with a bug-fix, your code would look like this:

```
' In any standard module
Option Explicit

Public NumRows As Long

Public Function GetTableSize() As Long
  GetTableSize = Worksheets("TableSize").Range("A1").Value2
End Function
```

```
' In the "ThisWorkbook" module
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  NumRows = GetTableSize()
End Sub
```

```
' In the "TableSize" sheet module
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim n As Long
    n = GetTableSize()
    If n > NumRows Then NewDatabaseEntry
    ' Always set NumRows so that even after entries are deleted (n < NumRows),
    ' adding new entries will work correctly.
    NumRows = n

End Sub
```

An even better idea would be to dispense with the "TableSize" helper worksheet and its `Worksheet_Calculate()` event handler, and instead use the `Worksheet_Change()` handler of Sheet 1 to directly detect added rows. (Not the `Worksheet_Calculate()` handler that you previously attempted to use.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't `worksheet_Change()` detect all changes, not just calculations? In a previous version of my code, I did use change but my routines kept firing when I was doing things like copying to multiple cells on a row, ruining usability.

Comment: @Remi Yes, that's the advantage (and disadvantage) of using `Worksheet_Change` in Sheet 1 (option 1) over `Worksheet_Calculate` in Sheet 1 (option 2). On the plus side for option 1 is if adding a row *doesn't* cause a calculation you can still detect it. The other minor benefit is that if you are working on a different sheet which causes a recalculation in Sheet 1, then it doesn't trigger. On the minus side, *every* change will cause it to fire, including edits to cells that don't cause a calculation. In either case you must detect if the number of rows have changed and exit immediately if…

Comment: …they haven't. That will fix any usability issue. What you are doing is option 3, where you moved the `Worksheet_Calculate` handler to a second sheet ("TableSize") and forced it to always calculate when a row is added by using a worksheet function formula. In all three cases, extra events are being triggered. It's just that you are (maybe unaware) that you are correctly handling them now using option 3, whereas when you attempted to use option 1 previously you weren't handling those extra triggers. …

Comment: It's just more natural to use "Change" to detect when something has changed, and to use the events on the actual sheet where the detection is required and work out if a row has been added directly, rather than involving *another* sheet and having an event handler there indirectly work out if a row has been added by using a formula in a cell. The code to work out if a row has been added is the same as the one you are currently using to determine the last cell of a column. I would have posted it, except it wasn't clear from your `A1` cell formula which sheet name/column to use.

Comment: you are a superstar. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you do not use Option Explicit in your modules and you put Private Sub Workbook_Open() into the Workbook module and Worksheet_Calculate into the sheet module. Because of the missing Option Explicit you will not get an error message that NumRows is an undefined variable. You cannot define and use global variables in class modules like you did. In order to fix your code you could put the following code into the workbook module

```
Option Explicit

Public NumRows As Long

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  NumRows = Worksheets("TableSize").Range("A1").Value
  MsgBox "NumRows = " & NumRows
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Dim n As Long

    If Sh.Name = "TableSize" Then

        n = Worksheets("TableSize").Range("A1").Value    'A1 contains the formula "=ROW(INDEX(Sheet1,1,1))+ROWS(Sheet1)-1" used to count rows on Sheet 1
        MsgBox n & "NumRows=" & NumRows
        If n = NumRows Then Exit Sub
        If n > NumRows Then
            Debug.Print "NewDatabaseEntry"
        End If

        NumRows = n
    End If

End Sub
```

An other option would be to add a standard module with the following code

```
Option Explicit

Public NumRows As Long

Private Sub Auto_Open()
  NumRows = Worksheets("TableSize").Range("A1").Value
  MsgBox "NumRows = " & NumRows
End Sub
```

And in the sheet module you would keep your code like that

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim n As Long
n = Worksheets("TableSize").Range("A1").Value    'A1 contains the formula "=ROW(INDEX(Sheet1,1,1))+ROWS(Sheet1)-1" used to count rows on Sheet 1
    MsgBox n & "NumRows=" & NumRows
    If n = NumRows Then Exit Sub
    If n > NumRows Then
        Debug.Print "NewDatabaseEntry"
    End If

    NumRows = n

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a compile error. Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having same name on the `Workbook_Calculate`

Comment: Which option did you try?  And I do not have a Workbook_Calculate in my code!

Comment: You are correct, sorry. I used the first option and it worked after correcting the name to Worksheet_SheetCalculate. Unfortunately now my code does not function. If I add a new row, NewDatabaseEntry does not run. I replaced the `Debug.Print "NewDatabaseEntry" with `Call NewDatabaseEntry`

Comment: Yes, of course you have to replace the `Debug.Print "NewDatabaseEntry" with Call NewDatabaseEntry`. But what do you mean with NewDatabaseEntry does not run. If you use in NewDatabaseEntry the variable NumRows that might not work, especially if `NewDatabaseEntry` is not contained in the workbook module.

Comment: I have only been using vba for 2 weeks so please explain this to me.  Do I need `NewDatabaseEntry` in the same worksheet as `Workbook_SheetCalculate`? Or as long as it's in the workbook it's fine? Because it is in the workbook, just in its own module.

Comment: In this case you have to consider that you cannot use `NumRows`in `NewDatabaseEntry` You have to pass along the variable as a parameter. And I still assume you do not use `Option Explicit` Please add this to every module.

Comment: Just to confirm, I will be adding `Option Explicit` to every module in my workbook, correct? Do you mean to just add it at the top of my modules?

Comment: Yes, and using `option Explicit` is good practise https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement After having added Option Explicit you might ged additional erros regarding variable declaration. Please fix that because otherwise you are in for a lot of surprises. Please try to understand scope fo variables http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html

Comment: I have added the `NewDatabaseEntry` module so you can see what it does

Comment: I cannot see what it does. How should I? And why is it a module?

Comment: as in, I added it to my original post so you can see what it does. It copies a named range to the bottom of a table on another  worksheet.

Comment: I am sorry but that's not the way SO works, at least IMHO. You had a question regarding your variable NumRows.  IMHO, that has beend fixed. As you do not use NumRows in `NewDatabaseentry` you now have a different issue with your code. Fine! But then open another question.